# Order rows by result of algorithm outside of db query

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order results of a db query based on an algorithm outside of the sql statement.

For example - each row has `author_karma` and `pageviews` columns. I'd like to order the result by an algorithm calculated in php after the rows are fetched...

The algorithm might look like this

`$score = intval($author_karma) + (intval($pageviews)/100) + intval($age)`

In sites like hacker news is this calculated in the sql query? How do they make this work? If I try to store the score in the db, how often to I update it (especially when time is involved in the score)?

Comment: You can order by a function in almost all databases.  So you would just use that function in your ORDER BY clause.

Comment: It will definitely help if you can post some relevant code... Since it might be possible to sort this in MySQL instead of having to interact with PHP after the fact..

Comment: @BrianHoover For a pretty simple algorithm like the one above, is it better to do it in the `order by` or store the score in the db?

Comment: @AndyPandy - I would probably do it in the order by, simply because all of those values are going to be changing pretty regularly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it in the query

```
select this, that, other, (author_karmar + ( pageviews/100 ) + age ) as score from table order by score desc
```